# Object reference not working even when there is a reference to it unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime-error

Hello there strangers,

I seem to be in a pickle over this matter, I have all the correct refrences for my scripts(I think!) but there is no object spawning and I keep getting the error message: Object refrence not set to an instance of an object

The following script is named PlayerController:

The error always trips on the following lines(Specifically the playerGun.isFiring) :

```
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        playerGun.isFiring = true;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        playerGun.isFiring = false;
    }
```

playerGun is assigned in the following way:

```
public GunController playerGun;
```

The folllowing script is the GunController Script:

This is where I assign the isFiring method, but nothing seem to happen as it breaks on the above code.

```
public bool isFiring; // Boolean to check if the player is firing
```

Any help/Suggestions are much appreciated. 
As a note the GunController is attached to an object which is a child of another object which holds the playerController script.

Comment: `public GunController playerGun;` does _not_ assign anything, it just _declares it.

Comment: @oerkelens So I need to set the playerGun to equal the script then? I don't get this error as it allows me to see all the public variables when i do playerGun.X/Y/Z  yet afterwards has an error...

Comment: "set the playerGun to equal the script" does not mean anything, I am sorry. You need to assign some value to playerGun, like `= new GunController();` or something. I have no idea what script you keep talking about.

Comment: @Robertgold the public variable should appear in inspector when you select PlayerController gameObject in Unity, drag and drop the gun object int the inspector and it will work

Comment: @UmairM Thanks that worked, I had completely forgotton that it could be that!